# Trying to use Log.d function from static context in Android

Tags: android, static-methods

Log.d seems to not be displaying anything in my terminal. Is this related to using a static method?

```
public static void setPosition(int pos){
        DetailActivity.pos = pos;
        DetailActivity.counter++;

        Log.d("counter", "" + counter);

        if(DetailActivity.counter == 1){
            //ad
            if (DetailActivity.mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                DetailActivity.mInterstitialAd.show();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you keep incrementing DetailActivity.counter in each method call. DetailActivity.counter Could be > 1 when you call it. What is the default value of DetailActivity.counter ?

Comment: could be better if you use boolean as the counter flag instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Log` is going to print to LogCat. In Android Studio, go to the `Android Monitor` tab to see this output.

You may add filters for your tag or message in the search box, for example entering "counter" should show your message.

Comment: Yup thank you, but its not showing any "counter" tag or info

Comment: Did you enter counter without quotes?

Comment: Yes, without quotes.

Comment: Try confirming that setPosition was actually called recent enough to see the output. Devices will output a lot of noise and the logs will not go indefinitely far back.

Comment: ahh it was my device. I'm using it via an emulator and it works now.